# Lucene Associate Price With Term

Tags: solr, filter, lucene

I have a document in a lucene which, say, models a shop.

The document has a number of terms which specify the items the shop has.  Now I want to associate a price with every item in the document without having to create extra fields for each item.  I want to be able to sort on these prices and filter on these prices.

How can I achieve this functionality?  I had thought of payloads for sorting, but not sure how to do the filtering part?

Comment: Any reason why you don't have a document pr. item instead of pr. shop?

Comment: No Just because i have the main entity as shop because after the search i wanna shows shops who provide that item and not the items in the listings.
And i was able to sort my shop documents using a payloadtermquery but i have no clue on how to range sort on payload values.